# How to use django packages in your app?

Tags: python, django, django-views, package

i am  making a car booking system. and beginner in web development its my first django project . i had covered poll app tutorial. i want to built a booking system . i want to use this package **https://github.com/bitlabstudio/django-booking** in my django application . i want to use this package features for my car booking . how do i attach and make it working with my app.

i dont know about django packages. how do i use this package for booking.what should i write and where should i write about booking . i had installed booking and covered all stuffs in Readme. but how do i initialize with my app . for eg i want to use there booking system for book my car

**Views.py**

```
    class CarDetailView(DetailView):
       context_object_name = 'car_details'
       model = models.Car
       template_name = 'buggy_app/car_detail.html'

    class BookingView(FormView):
         template_name = 'buggy_app/booking.html'
         form_class = BookingForm
         models = Booking
         def form_valid(self, form):
           form.save()
           return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)

        success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

                try:
                  kwargs['car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('car', ''))
               except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
                   kwargs['car'] = None

              return super(BookingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 

         def get_initial(self):
            initial = super(BookingView, self).get_initial()
            if 'car' in self.request.GET:
                try:
                   initial['book_car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET['car'])
                except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
                     pass
                return initial
```

**Models.py**

```
class Booking(models.Model):

  booking_name = models.CharField(max_length=240, null=False)
  customer_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_customers' )
  book_car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_car')
  booking_start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
  booking_end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  rental_price = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
  times_pick = models.TimeField(blank=True)
  is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.booking_name

  def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse("buggy_app:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Comment: This question is not clear. The app has a detailed readme; what do you think is not covered there? Where are you having problems?

Comment: @DanielRoseman hi . i dont know about packages . means how do i use that package for booking . what should i write and where should i wirte about booking . i had installed all that stuffs that is in readme and dont know how to configure with my app